# CNSetSupportedSSIDs returning false/ not working correctly?

Tags: iphone

I tried to use CaptiveNetwork in order to replace the web sheet that for user authentication with the network. The method is CNSetSupportedSSIDs.
I tried to add the list, but the web sheet for user authentication still keeps popping up every time I open up my App.
I tried to debug it and I realized that I keep getting the return Value as FALSE.

This is my Code:

```
-(void)updateSSIDlist

{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ssidInitStarted" object:nil    userInfo:nil];
 ATT_Remote_Access_Wifi_ClientAppDelegate *delegate = (ATT_Remote_Access_Wifi_ClientAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

delegate.ssidInitFinished = NO;
Hotspots *h = [Hotspots defaultHotspots];
NSArray *ssids2 = [h uniqueSSIDs];
NSLog(@"ssids we're shoving down into the system config for iOS to leave alone: %@", [ssids2 description]); 

bool ok = CNSetSupportedSSIDs((CFArrayRef) ssids2);

if(ok)
 {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]   postNotificationName:@"ssidInitCompleted" object:nil userInfo:nil];
NSLog(@"completed");    
}
else
{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ssidInitFailed" object:nil userInfo:nil];
NSLog(@"failed"); 
}

delegate.ssidInitFinished = YES;
delegate.dbIsBusy = NO;
 }
```

I searched a LOT, but I couldn't find any correct examples or documentation on this.
I also tried the below link example, but even that retuned the same results.

Any help is Appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *values[] = {@"yourssid"};    
CFArrayRef arrayRef = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (void *)values, (CFIndex)1, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);    
if( CNSetSupportedSSIDs(arrayRef))
{
    NSLog(@"Successfully registered supported network SSIDs");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Error: Failed to register supported network SSIDs");
}
```

the login page is blocked but my application will not be called. let's share the experience. thank you